# Wordpress rewrite rule - not able to access second and third parameters

Tags: rewrite-rules

I have a rewrite rule;

```php
  add_rewrite_rule(
    'jobs/search/([^/]+)/state/([^/]+)/position/([^/]+)/?$',
    'index.php?post_type=job&search=$matches[1]&state=$matches[2]&position=$matches[3]',
    'top'
  );
```

It correctly loads the jobs page and I am able to access the search query var, however trying to get state and position returns blank.

Example URL: `https://website.com/jobs/search/chef/state/nsw/position/full-time/`

Current result:

[image: current_result]

Expected result:

[image: expected_result]

What am I missing here?

Comment: How did you check those results, what code/plugin you used to generate/display the arrays? What are the `state` and `position`?

Comment: @SallyCJ it's just a custom function I wrote which uses get_query_var() to get the variables passed through the URL.

Comment: Can you add that to your post, and also answer my other question? Are `state` and `position` the slug of custom taxonomy or post type, or are they just custom parameters?